# What is the difference between geocoding and georeferencing?

Tags: geocoding, georeferencing, oracle-spatial

After some googling around both seem to be interchangable words, where we speak of tying the spatial info of a real place and storing in database.

But still I am not satisfied, there should be some major differences. Also are there any tools in `Oracle Spatial` suite for this to carry out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To easily understand these terms, let's use example of an online mapping service (say Google maps, Mapquest etc.)

- When you type an address or a placename in the searchbox and in return the map shows a marker at the place. The process of associating an address or a placename with coordinates on the map is called **Geocoding**. In a spatial database this is done as a point layer with name of the place as an attribute to the point location. This is one way of geocoding. For addresses, the associated coordinates are not saved in a database directly, but computed using a  method called linear referencing. (Thus the confusion between the terms *geo-referencing* and *linear-referencing* ) The start and end addresses along a line segment are saved and intermediate addresses are interpolated and the coordinates are calculated. As for your question, Oracle spatial has linear referencing support. http://docs.oracle.com/html/A88805_01/sdo_lrsa.htm
- In some online mapping service, you may have seen satellite imagery. When these images are captured from a satellite or an airplane, they are just plain images, like photographs. But to display these images on a map, they need to be associated with map coordinates. This process is called **GeoReferencing**. Once the image is associated with the map coordinates it can be overlaid on top of street maps. For georeferencing, you can use a GIS software such as ArcGIS or QGIS to georeference an otherwise un-referenced image or scanned maps, and load them into Oracle Spatial.

Comment: You can certainly have address points stored in the database, which are considered more accurate (especially important for emergency services routing).

Answer (score 13):

I see them as separate activities.

**Geocoding** is the process of taking *coded* location information (such as addresses or grids) and turning it into explicit location information (X and Y coordinates, usually). **Reverse geocoding** is the opposite, taking XY data and locating the nearest address, grid, etc.

**Georeferencing** is the process of taking a raster image or vector coverage, assigning it a coordinate system and coordinates, and translating, transforming, and warping/[rubbersheeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbersheeting) it into position relative to some other spatial data, such as survey locations, street intersections, etc.

This can be sometimes also be called [rectification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification) or georectification interchangeably, while in some contexts, georeferencing is considered to only include the assigning of a spatial reference and coordinates to the image, and rectification is the transformation and [resampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28bitmap%29) of the image to remove distortion (as in [orthorectification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthorectification)).

In ArcGIS, [georeferencing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Fundamentals_for_georeferencing_a_raster_dataset/009t000000mn000000/) is transitory (on-the-fly transformation of the source image) while rectification is permanent (creating a new resampled image given a georeferenced raster layer).

Answer (score 6):

My abbreviated take:

**Georeferencing** involves fitting an image to the Earth based on matching up visual features of the image with their known location.

- Input: Imagery, Image control points, Matching geospatial control points
- Output: Image with data attached showing how it fits onto the globe

**Geocoding** involves converting some human placename or label into coordinates.  Often this is done thousands of items at a time.

- Input: "642 Arbitrary Lane, Cityville, MA" or "Miami" or "FIPS county #64623", large database of spatial reference info
- Output: "53.645 N, 73.6453 W"

Comment: You can also georeference a vector. Perhaps you have imported CAD data that represents a utility network (but contains no spatial reference) to vector format. If you were to rubbersheet that vector to a basemap, probably imagery or an image that has been scanned and georef'd, then you would have georef'd the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I use the term "georeferencing" when I am referring to applying geographic information to data.  Such as "georeferencing an image" so it will align with the rest of my data.  I'll use "geocoding" when I have address/post code information and I want to georeference them.

[Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) on Wikipedia

[Georeferencing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeference) on Wikipedia

But you probably read those anyway.

Maybe someone else can speak about the tools in Oracle Spatial.

Comment: You actually described reverse geocoding (assigning address/postcodes to spatial data).

Comment: Thanks, you're right.  I actually gave a demonstration to people at work for geocoding addresses using Google Fusion.  I got mixed up somehow.  I've edited my post to reflect the correct definition.